# Position relative to scroll area

Tags: css, scroll, position

I want to absolutely position a div at the top and bottom of a scrolling area so they stay in place while I scroll inside the div.

They the scroll area has `position: relative;` set and the div's I want pinned to the top and bottom are absolutely positioned at `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;`

Initially they are positioned as expected but when you scroll they scroll inside the scroll area.

Here is a code pen showing my problem:
http://codepen.io/JoeHastings/pen/wKJzNb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know of any way to fix an element inside another without using javascript. If you know the position of the box, you can used fixed positioning like this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjeRQQ

```
.transcript {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #ffcc00;
    overflow-y: scroll;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        width: 400px; height: 20px;
        margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    }

    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        top: 140px; left: 0;
        width: 400px; height: 20px;

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for my scenario I do know the position of the box and it's a fixed height so this will work

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if this is what's needed, but `sticky` position will maintain a div at the top of the scrolling area ([live demo](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_sticky)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cae8ca;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Try to <b>scroll</b> inside this frame to understand how sticky positioning works.</p>
<p>Note: IE/Edge 15 and earlier versions do not support sticky position.</p>

<div class="sticky">I am sticky!</div>

<div style="padding-bottom:2000px">
  <p>In this example, the sticky element sticks to the top of the page (top: 0), when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change .transcript position to static.

```
.transcript {
    position: static;
}
```

leave the rest intact and that should work ...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGpdBY